# Как переслать экземпляр класса по сети?

Tags: eclipse, java, сервер

Привет всем!

Столкнулся с проблемой: есть сервер и клиент. На сервере есть объект класса.
Нужно переслать этот самый объект класса клиенту. Как это сделать?

На стороне сервера я написал:

```
public static class GameData implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7918700940677946167L;
        int player1Position;
        int player1Score;
        int player1Ping;
    }
....
// Send class DATA
    GameData gameData = new GameData();
    gameData.player1Ping = 60;
    gameData.player1Score = 10;
    gameData.player1Position = 50;

    // Serialize object
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4 * 1024);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(gameData);
    byte[] objectBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    // UDP Packet from Server 
    outD.write(objectBytes);// Здесь, по идее, отсылается обьект класса.
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    objectOutputStream.close();
```

На стороне клиента:

```
   ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
   MyThreadWorker obj = (MyThreadWorker)objectInputStream.readObject();// вот тут эксепшен (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server_mdl.FileSender$GameData).
   objectInputStream.close();
```

MyThreadWorker имплементирует Serializable.

Информацию брал [отсюда](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/objectinputstream.html) и [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674599/how-should-i-send-class-or-struct-data-over-udp-in-java). 
Почему вылетает эксепшен?

Server ClassPath

[image]

//-----------------------------------------------------------

Client ClassPath:

[image]

Comment: Класс, экземпляры которого вы сериализуете/десериализуете, должен быть доступен в CLASSPATH и клиента, и сервера. Скорее всего, в вашем случае клиент не имеет информации об этом классе.

Comment: Эммм, я не особо разбираюсь в этом. Можете пояснить что значит "доступен в CLASSPATH"??? Это как?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаеш classpath? Учи [это](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html). Это основа основ.

Comment: Ааа, понял. А как это мешает десериализовать класс?

Comment: А почему он должен десериализовыватся? Что ты сделал для этого?

Comment: Серверу получилось принять сериализованный класс. Одно но: как получить объявленные и инициализированные поля в классе??? Я не слишком силен именно в этой области, т.к. только ее осваиваю. )